# Android resources error

Tags: java, android, resources, android-resources

I used a `getResources(`) call to read from a `raw text file` and I'm getting this error. If I don't call `getResources()` I don't seem to get any error at all.

```
VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 387: Landroid/content/res/Resources;.getDrawable (ILandroid/content/res/Resources$Theme;)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
```

This is the code:

```
Resources res = getResources();
InputStream in_s = res.openRawResource(R.raw.gg);
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: Where calling `getDrawable ` method?

Comment: I don't actually call it in my code.

Comment: In your question you say that you did use getResources(), but in your comment you say you don't call it in your code.  This seems contradictory to me.  Maybe you could say more about what is actually happening here, or paste the whole class where this code bit lives.